# Merging two photos in MATLAB, excluding pixels that are black ([0 0 0])

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have two matrices, let's call them photo1 and photo2, and I want to merge them in the following sense:

Whenever `photo2(i,j,:)` was different from `[0 0 0]`, set `photo1(i,j,:)=photo2(i,j,:)`.

Obviously, I can write it using for-loops. But that's too slow. I'm looking for a solution that uses the idea of vectorization in MATLAB.

I tried

```
[row,column,channel] = find(photo2);
photo1(row,column,channel) = photo2(row,column,channel);
```

Based on MATLAB's documentation but it doesn't work. It gave the 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.' error and I don't know why. I have fiddled with both sub2ind and ind2sub for a while, but I'm stuck. I'm still a beginner in MATLAB. Anyway, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is better to provide both photos. It seems that they have different sizes.

Comment: @rahnema1 the photos are randomly generated. Here's how they are generated: I first generate a 6 by 9 checkerboard pattern. Then I create a pinhole camera matrix which has fixed distance from the checkerboard, but its position can be randomly changed by small Euler rotations. Each time I run the algorithm, I'll get different photos. Let me upload a better photo.

Comment: Do they have the same size?

Comment: @rahnema1 Yes, they have the same size. They are 6 by 9. The difference in their size is probably due to wrong camera angle in my calculations. I was creating a new photo that my computer crashed and I had to restart it. I will edit it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `[i,j,v] = find(x)` doesn't behave the way you expect it to, check out  the [documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html). This command only finds the 2d-indices `i,j` of the nonzero entries as well as the values `v` of these entries. It is the same as if you would write `[i,j] = find(x(:,:)); v = x(i,j);`.

To fix this, we first determine the non-black entries by `or`-ing across the channels, then we convert our `sub`-indices to linear indices using `sub2ind`, and use these to overwrite the corresponding pixels.

```matlab
photo1 = [];
photo1(:,:,1) = [1,1,1;0,0,0;1,1,1];
photo1(:,:,2) = [1,1,1;0,0,0;1,1,1];
photo1(:,:,3) = [1,1,1;0,0,0;1,1,1];

photo2 = [];
photo2(:,:,1) = [2,0,2;2,0,2;2,0,2];
photo2(:,:,2) = [2,0,2;2,0,2;2,0,2];
photo2(:,:,3) = [2,0,2;2,0,2;2,0,2];


[row,column] = find(photo2(:,:,1)|photo2(:,:,2)|photo2(:,:,3));
ind1 = sub2ind(size(photo1), [row;row;row], [column;column;column],[row*0+1;row*0+2;row*0+3]);
ind2 = sub2ind(size(photo2), [row;row;row], [column;column;column],[row*0+1;row*0+2;row*0+3]);

photo1(ind2) = photo2(ind1);

disp(photo1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHLCoMwEEX3@QqXpp2FGXcO/RLJolVLhdZIfRSK/55mGgUDFVyUkEweZ@7NJKboz2NlbXszvVHRKco1Cb@IM8hASd5T4Bol4Bp95yGEe6B0E/IUrs1xZY4ORlqNIYR7oHQTEiJ/mhcU5j48Gu2oa92UcXCJKXCbAllJwvH8cN1wQU7t6nfl85WEiMVp7totvQ8FQQNTh@SoyEecY6q9PP6Ux7/IL1/ENvxIc3VcFJ@Wddcu1ZCw9gM)

Comment: Thank you. (+1) Could you explain the sub2ind part please? How did you come up with it?

Comment: We convert 3d (`row,col,channel`) indices to 1d-indices. So for every non-black entry, we need to convert the 3d indices of all three dimensions into 1d indices. So we need to access each `row,column` three times, once for each channel. That is why we concatenate these tree times. The remaining argument just provdes the three channel indices.

Comment: How does linear ordering work in 3D arrays in MATLAB? It first reads the first matrix column by column and then goes to the next one? Or does it first read the first columns of all matrices and then goes to the second columns of them, so on so forth? Sorry if my question is basic.

Comment: I recommend trying it yourself! I wrote a little script [here](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbO4QEPdKEUhtSIxtyAn1Upd05orUcFWIT8vtVjDWMcYxNWw0gSKGFppGGuB@GA9iUAGhKVujEO3iY6xjhGKfhMtYy0jJBP@/wcA) that hopefully explains quite visually how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these methods:

Method1:

We can reshape a 3D matrix to a 2D. Using `any` we can find those pixels that don't contain 0.  Then [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) is used to extract the desired elements.

```
s = size(photo1);
photo1 = reshape(photo1,[],3);
photo2 = reshape(photo2,[],3);
idx = any(photo2,2);
photo1(idx,:)= photo2(idx,:);
photo1 = reshape(photo1 ,s);
```

Method2:

Here again we can use `any`. `idx` is a mask. We multiply the image by the mask to retain those values that are under the mask and to set other pixels to zero. Because of [implicit expantion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/11/10/more_thoughts_about_implicit_expansion) the mask is applied to all three channels.

```
idx = any(photo2,3);
photo1 = photo1 .* ~idx + photo2 .* idx;
```

Comment: This is very beautiful (+1). But could you please explain why you used any instead of find? They seem to do the same thing. Also, I don't understand your second method.

Comment: I have used [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). For the first method you can do `f = find(idx);` and use `f` instead of `idx`.